# Android - Resolve short urls from intent-filters

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, short-url

Got a weird issue with short urls.

I have an Activity with 2 different intent-filters to catch the regular urls, but also the short urls provided by the same website (Dribbble).

Here's my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SomeActivity">

        <!-- For "regular" urls -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="dribbble.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/shots/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        ...
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- For short urls -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="drbl.in"
                android:scheme="http" />
        ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here are 2 examples of the urls matching these intent-filters:

- **Regular url:** https://dribbble.com/shots/2278534-Google-Now-Animation
- **Short url:** http://drbl.in/qkHY

Retrieving normal urls works as expected. But when trying to resolve a shortened url coming from Android's stock browser, the url received in the Activity is a mix of both types of urls. Ie it is composed of the host + suffix of the regular urls, but the path of the short url. With the previous example, it looks like this:

- **Expected short url :** http://drbl.in/qkHY
- **Actual url received in Activity:** https://dribbble.com/shots/qkHY

So, when I try to resolve the short url in my Activity, my code doesn't enter the condition testing if the url is a shot url:

```
class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        resolveUrl(getIntent().getData());
        ...
    }

    private void resolveUrl(Uri url) {
        if (url.getHost().equals("drbl.in")) { // Condition never met
            resolveShortUrl(url);
        } else {
            getIdFromUrl(url);
        }
    }

    ... 
}
```

Can somebody tell me what the heck am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can somebody tell me what the heck am I doing wrong?

If you run **`curl -v http://drbl.in/qkHY`**, you will get something akin to:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.6.188.250...
* Connected to drbl.in (52.6.188.250) port 80 (#0)
> GET /qkHY HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: drbl.in
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 13:14:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 193
< Location: https://dribbble.com/shots/qkHY
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host drbl.in left intact
```

Hence, Dribble is redirecting the short URL to a `dribble.com` URL with the short code in the path. Android has nothing to do with it, other than being the one executing the HTTP request.

If you execute **`curl -v https://dribbble.com/shots/qkHY`** (the redirected-to URL), Dribble issues *another* redirect response, though one with a MIME type:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.6.188.250...
* Connected to dribbble.com (52.6.188.250) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Massachusetts; serialNumber=001031096; street=Ste. 202; street=16 Front St.; postalCode=01970; C=US; ST=Massachusetts; L=Salem; O=Dribbble LLC; CN=dribbble.com
*    start date: 2014-12-31 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-04-29 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: dribbble.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /shots/qkHY HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: dribbble.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 13:16:25 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Status: 301 Moved Permanently
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Location: https://dribbble.com/shots/2278534-Google-Now-Animation
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: _dribbble_session=eGhSVTlDV1NEMzBiTUlLMTA0YWlkQ0YzWUJiYUM2cGVGQ1J1cFZYTE9xL3R3UEsvb0VWS1paU1U3bkNRdlh1V3JJZ2JqdW1veTM0azMrTVFRUUlMYUE9PS0tdC9uQTlNR0xvKy9GQmx0R3BkTUtWQT09--9873ba3016e4ab9a99f6a237a975610c01c1eb15; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-Request-Id: 5359c3d6-9d64-4637-8ff5-014e8e44d503
< X-Runtime: 0.006814
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< 
* Connection #0 to host dribbble.com left intact
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://dribbble.com/shots/2278534-Google-Now-Animation">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

An HTTP `HEAD` request (add `-X HEAD` to the **`curl`** command) returns the same basic stuff, minus the body.

My best guess is that Android sees the `Content-type` header on the second `HEAD` request and goes ahead to use that URL for `Intent` resolution. There is very little that you can do about this, as I presume that you control neither Android nor Dribble. However, you can always get the full URL yourself by issuing your own `HEAD` request from within your Java code.

Comment: Thanks for this quick, detailed and accurate answer. Will try to work with that.

Comment: @MathieuMaree is this still the case today? How did you solve this?